# Yii2 doesn't find /backend/web after .htaccess changes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, path, yii2

I'm trying to get an Yii2 advanced template up on a VPS. Everything works fine in terms of algorithms and pathing until I try to enable 'pretty url' through config files and .htaccess. It works perfectly for /frontend, but /backend can no longer be accessed. I'm still a newbie on .htaccess so any help would be appreciated.

Root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule backend backend\.php [T=application/x-httpd-php]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

common\config\main.php (urlManager)

```
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [ 
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',     
            ],
        ],
```

frontend/web/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I've also tried changing the frontend/config/main.php **basePath** as such:

```
use yii\web\Request;
$baseUrl = str_replace('/frontend/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());
```

But to no avail, since I would only get a 500 error (and nothing else) while trying to access the server.

Note: mode_rewrite has been enabled both through a2enmod and through apache2.conf.

Comment: I guess this is what you looking for: https://gist.github.com/ptflp/8706c0fbd697e93e486b2df024f2ea47

Comment: Please add it as an aswer so that I may mark it as the correct answer. Thank you lots for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii2 advanced .htaccess configuration

**.htaccess**

```
Options -Indexes
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/$
RewriteRule ^(admin)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)?$ /backend/web/$1 [L,PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/web/$1
```

**.htaccess - backend**

```
# use mode rewrite for pretty URL support
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**.htaccess - frontend**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymlinks

        # Включаем mod_rewrite и перенаправляем со слэша
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [L,R=301]

        # Если это папка или файл, открываем ее/его
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        # В противном случае перенаправляем на index.php
        RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

Hope it helps